# How can I fix could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/csharpfile.txt"

Tags: c#, android, filestream

It says `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/csharpfile.txt".` for the file path directory

```
//FILESTREAM     
     private static void FileStream()
     {
       Console.Clear();
       FileStream fs = new FileStream("/storage/emulated/0/FPAct8_(Ray)/csharpfile.txt",
       FileMode.Create);
       fs.Close();
       Console.WriteLine("File has been created and the path is /storage/emulated/0/FPAct8_(Ray)/csharpfile.txt");
     }
//STREAMWRITER     
     private static void StreamWriter()
     {
       string file = @"/storage/emulated/0/FPAct8_(Ray)/csharpfile.txt";
       using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter (file)){
         writer.Write("Hello!");
         writer.Write("This is Ray");
         writer.Write("BSIT-1C");
         writer.Write("This is StreamWriter");
       }
       Console.WriteLine("Data Saved Successfully");
     }
//STREAMREADER     
     private static void StreamReader()
     {
       string file = @"/storage/emulated/0/FPAct8_(Ray)/csharpfile2.txt";
       using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (file)){
         Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
       }
     }
//TEXTWRITER
     private static void TextWriter()
     {
       string file = @"/storage/emulated/0/FPAct8_(Ray)/csharpfile.txt";
       using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(file)){
         writer.WriteLine("Hello");
         writer.WriteLine("This is TextWriter");
       }
       Console.WriteLine("Entry stored successfully");
     }
//TEXTREADER     
     private static void TextReader()
     {
       string filepath = @"/storage/emulated/0/FPAct8_(Ray)/csharpfile.txt";
       using(TextReader tr = File.OpenText(filepath)){
         Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadToEnd());
      }
```

I've already search on google and here about the file path directory and the only thing I found is `/storage/emulated/0/` but it doesn't work and the others are for desktop but what I need is for android.

`Dcoder` is the IDE that I use, btw.

Edit: I also try `Phone Storage:\\csharpfile.txt` but this time it says `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/home/user/Phone Storage:\csharpfile.txt" is denied.` and I need it to be directed to a folder because that's what my teacher says but when I add a folder it goes back to `could not find path`.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Server.MapPath(@"/storage/emulated/0/FPAct8_(Ray)/csharpfile.txt");
```